# replacing an option with an empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assume we have three options in html select
i.e select, Male, Female.
On click I want to replace select with "".

The below code I tried.

```
<select id="ageID">
    <option value="none" >loading...</option>
    <option value="one" >one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>  

$("#ageID").on("click",function(){

    $(this).children().first().remove();
    $(this).children().first().before(" <option value='none' > </option>");

});
```

It works perfectly on google chrome but not on mozilla or IE.
you can try running it using http://jsfiddle.net/
Please provide a solution

Comment: Please describe what's not working in FF/IE.

Comment: Why removing "loading..." on click and not when what is being loaded has finished loaded ?

Comment: I am not able to select the newly added option(empty value) in FF. And in IE, dropdown appears for a fraction of seconds and disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$("#ageID").on("click focus",function(){
    this.options[0].text='';
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ozamoz/2/)

I added the `focus` event because I thought you wanted the change to be made as soon as possible (which wouldn't be the case with only `click`).

Comment: @prakash I tested it in chrome. What's your problem (and version of chrome) ?

Comment: sorry it works in FF. Not in IE. The dropdown appears and disappear in a fraction of time

Comment: Do you really want it to work on `click` ? Couldn't you simply bind it to the focus event ? I edited to remove the `click` event which seems a bad idea.

Comment: please check from your side. I need to write a common code which works all the three browsers. And I am bit new to jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#ageID").on("click",function(){

    $(this).children().first().remove();
    $(this).children().first().before('<option value="none"> </option>');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

why not try this:

```
$("#ageID").on("click",function(){
    $('option:first',this).text('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

```
$("#ageID").on("click",function(){

    $(this).children().first().remove();
    $(this).prepend("<option value='' ></option>");

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can mimic this with simple CSS:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E4ah9/

HTML

```
<select id="ageID">
    <option value="none" disabled selected class="placeholder">loading...</option>
    <option value="one" >one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
.placeholder { display: none; }
```

Comment: it does not remove the first item immediately, but the "placeholder" is no longer available after choosing an item, which is what is being asked (if I interpret the question correctly)